# A single verb or phrasal verb that means "I have no choice but it is better if I let you win"?

Tags: word-requests

Consider the following situations:

- Your mother has just one cake. You and your younger brother really like that cake. If you eat the cake, your younger brother will cry. As you are older so you must be wise, you let him eat the cake as if you let him win.
- You meet a crazy guy on the train. He rudely asked you to leave your seat. As you are wise enough, you let him take your seat as if you let him win.

## Question

Is there a single verb or phrasal verb to convey the meaning of "I have no choice but I think it is better to let him win"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first verb that comes to mind is 「[譲]{ゆず}る」("***to hand over***").  It is a very useful verb that unfortunately, not too many Japanese-learners around me use actively.

In your first situation, you could say to your little brother:

> 「しょうがない。このケーキ（は）お[前]{まえ}に譲るよ/譲ってあげるよ。」
>
> 「[仕方]{しかた}（が）ないから、このケーキ（は）お前に譲ろう/譲ってあげよう。」

「お前」 can, of course, be replaced by your brother's actual name or nickname that you usually address him with.

In your second situation, you probably would not want to say too many words, would you?  You could just say:

> 「どうぞ。」 pointing to the now empty seat.

But if you have to use a verb for practice, you could say:

> 「わかりました。お譲りします/お譲りしましょう。」